# Android Studio: java.exe finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

new to Android Studio.

I've just created a new blank app and added a new Google Cloud Module.
After adding the module I get the error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

I have read the multiple answers here on StackOverflow, all suggesting an error with gradle dependencies, however I cannot see one. Here are my two gradle files:

build.gradle (Module: app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.bristow.conor.intellipa"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
}
```

build.gradle (Module: backend)

```
// If you would like more information on the gradle-appengine-plugin please refer to the github page
// https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.18'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

dependencies {
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.18'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.18'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.18'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    compile 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:4.0b3'
    compile 'com.ganyo:gcm-server:1.0.2'
}

appengine {
    downloadSdk = true
    appcfg {
        oauth2 = true
    }
    endpoints {
        getClientLibsOnBuild = true
        getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = true
    }
}
```

I do not see any duplicates nor am I using a '+' with the version numbers that seem to solve other peoples problems. I haven't added/modified or tinkered with the project yet bar adding the module. Prior to adding the module, it compiles correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in gradle file

```
defaultConfig {        
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'`
instead of `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'`